# Android R8 Build Release Apk fail

Tags: android, android-build

minifyEnabled=false build success,minifyEnabled=false build fail

build debugApk is success but build releaseApk is fail

please help me,I can't find the problem

```
FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
Stack trace:
com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.b(:57)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(:390)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(:336)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.U0.a(:10)
...
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)]
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: FORCE inlining on non-inlinable: void io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable.constructor$io$reactivex$rxjava3$disposables$ReferenceDisposable(java.lang.Object)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.T.a(:42)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this phenomena with RxJava3 ver. 3.0.6, too.
The cause is that R8 tries to remove the method and inline it at the single call site.
See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code in detail.
So, if our app calls `RunnableDisposable.constructor` from multiple places, this issue doesn't happen.
I mean that if two or more kinds of extended classes of `RunnableDisposable` are used, we don't encounter this issue.
And the workaround is adding the following proguard rule simply.

```
-keep class io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.RunnableDisposable { <init>(...); }
```